# Assuming I have control over the server, is there any point in including <meta charset> in my HTML?

Tags: html, http, utf-8, character-encoding, meta-tags

I'm running a web site where I have full control of the server and the page content.

I'm currently serving all the pages using the UTF-8 text encoding. I'm declaring this in the HTTP `Content-Type` header (`text/html; charset=utf-8`), and in the HTML (`<meta charset="utf-8">`).

As I understand it, user-agents should (and do) give the HTTP header precedence over the HTML tag.

Given that I'm declaring the encoding in the HTTP header, is there any point in including it in the HTML too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

This will make sure that the page is rendered correctly for users behind broken proxies that strip or mangle the header.

Comment: Aha, I'd not thought of that at all. Right, so if the header is removed or rendered inert by a proxy, the end user-agent still has the `<meta>` tag as a fallback. Cool.

Comment: Are they many broken proxies that remove or mangle the http content-type header? You'd think they'd be almost unusable.

Comment: They might just be mis-configured proxies, rather than broken.

Comment: Perhaps a more common case is a page saved locally on the user’s disk. Browsers generally do not save information from HTTP headers when doing the operation. If the document is UTF-8 encoded with BOM, then the encoding will be recognized when the local file is opened, but otherwise browsers will use `meta` tags or apply various heuristics, which often go wrong.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: I was wondering about that. My thinking was that if the file has been saved locally, then all bets are off anyway, because the file could have been re-saved with whatever text encoding the program/user wanted. But I do see what you’re getting at.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: plus it does at least indicate the page author's intentions.